# Run-Time Error '2147217904(80040e10)': No Value given for one or more required parameters in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When I run a query with Sheet Name as Sheet1 it is running fine where the file has onnly one sheet (Sheet1). When I use the same query in another file where it has 4 sheets and "Details" is 4th sheet it is showing the above error.

For Query (file with single sheet "Sheet1") it is working fine  - strQuery = "Select [Region], [Branch], [Prod], [AgNo], [PartyName], [AgDate], [BizMon],  [Hub], [FileStatus], [RecdDate] from [Sheet1$] where [Region] = '" & StrRegion & "' And [FileStatus] = 'Received' Order By [RecdDate], [Branch]"

? strquery (file with 4 sheets and 4th sheet name is "Details") it is showing error
Select [Region], [Branch], [Prod], [AgNo], [PartyName], [AgDate], [BizMon],  [Hub], [FileStatus], [RecdDate] from [Details$] where [Region] = 'AP' And [FileStatus] = 'Received' Order By [RecdDate], [Branch].

Checked the field names and everything is fine and correct.

Error is coming on the code line - rs.Open strQuery, objCon, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

For info I give the detials of str query (above) and objCon and strconstring too

? strConString
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\sram\Desktop\General\Scan_Pending_20220331.xlsx';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;";

? objcon
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\sram\Desktop\General\Scan_Pending_20220331.xlsx;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False;

Please guide me where is the error and how to correct

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you are not showing your code, as it is in your VBA Editor...

Comment: Not much code than what I have already shared here. Sorry for the delayed reply. Please help to resolve.

Comment: What is written above, if you had copied that into the VBA editor, it would clearly do nothing, other than crashing. So it is not the code shared. You have shared some code snipets with your comments inserted into it inbetween. But even those comments seems to have come about by your thoughts as they came, while you wrote your question, instead of proper programming comments. There is a reason why no one has touched your question. It is impossible to see through. What are you trying to do with the lines which start with a question mark ? Like `? strConString Provider=Micro...`

Comment: Those lines are as if they have been used in the Immediate Window of the IDE... so they don't seem to be part of the code...